# I removed gnome-screensaver

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, screensaver, recovery-mode

I removed gnome-screensaver to install xscreensaver, but for some reason, it failed to run gnome-shell. I ran It manually but it failed. I also do sudo dpkg but no work. Before that, I installed kingsoft-office but when I install it, it took too much time to respond so I cancelled it and shutdown the computer by unplug the power cable. But, I went to the recovery mode ,turn on the network , and ran sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver, it says

```
The package kingsoft-office needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I also ran software-center but it crashed.

Comment: Does anything happen differently if you run `sudo apt-get update` before running `... upgrade`? Also, please edit your question to include as much information as possible about *how* you installed (or started to install) [Kingsoft Office](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingsoft_Office), as this is not a program provided in the usual Ubuntu software sources. Please also add more detailed information about what you mean when yous say Software Center crashed. (Was there an error message of some kind?)

Answer (score 1):

Open `/var/lib/dpkg/status` with the following commands in terminal:

```bsh
sudo -i    #  to grant access as root
gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

When it opens, search through the file for `kingsoft-office` package and delete that entry (delete everything from the line `Package: kingsoft-office` until next line that starts with `Package: ...`). Don't delete anything else. Save the file and close it. And in terminal type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to logout from root account.

Then, again in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver
```

Comment: What's the effect of this (if any) on future attempts to install Kingsoft Office from a `deb` file?

Comment: @EliahKagan This happened due to forced interruption of the installation and `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file became corrupted. Because of `sudo apt-get update` that package will be added again, but this time correctly. So, installation should proceed normally this time.